# vi /etc/network/interfaces no such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, directory

When I install initial configuration in Ubuntu 12.04 Server, I type this command to change the network interface card (NIC) from using DHCP to a static IP:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

out put  is :

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces  no such file or directory
```

Should I create this directory or what ?

Comment: Try `cd /etc/network/` and do `ls` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

You must leave a space between vi and the file so it should be 
`vi /etc/network/interfaces`
Also , in order for you to change that file, you need to be root so i would suggest you put  it as `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes , It's working .